# How do I escape CoffeeScript reserved words?

Tags: coffeescript, qunit

I'm trying to run some unit tests using QUnit written in CoffeeScript but there seems to be some reserved words that are causing problems, most notably "not". Is there a way to escape a CoffeeScript reserved word? Here's a simple test that demonstrates the problem:

```
module "Sad face test"

test "will not compile", ->
    not false, "holy crap this creates a syntax error :-("
```

The error this generates is "Parse error on line 3: Unexpected ','"

Comment: Your question is how to call a function called "not", right?

Comment: Yes. "Not" is a function in qunit but is also a coffeescript keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `not` function is global, so it's actually attached to `window`, right? Instead of backtick escapes, then, you can just write

```
window.not
```

instead of `not`; or

```
notEqual = window.not
```

Comment: looks like

    module "Sad face test"

    test "will not compile", ->
        window.not false, "holy crap this creates a syntax error :-("

works great, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The best answer I have been able to find is to escape into JavaScript and alias the function:

```
notEqual = `not`

module "Sad face test"

test "will not compile", ->
    notEqual false, "holy crap this creates a syntax error :-("
```

Although it looks like `not` isn't a function within the latest version of QUnit, so in this specific instance you may not need to to escape a CoffeeScript reserved word.

Comment: Can be reduced to: `notEqual = ｀not｀`

Comment: I like this answer but Trevor's answer seems cleaner to me